# PLO100 - Top Two Facing Turn Aggression on Wet Board

Tags: online, hand-history

Pot-Limit Omaha, $1.00 BB (6 handed)

Limited time at the table, so not a lot of history with anyone. As far as I can tell, MP plays straight-forward and is a bit weak/passive. In one hand in the last orbit, CO checked a draw-heavy flop, check/called a blank turn and then check-raised all-in on a blank river.

**Hero (BB) ($100)**
UTG ($141.35)
**MP ($103.60)**
**CO ($116)**
Button ($217.70)
SB ($203.65)

**Preflop**: Hero is BB with 2♥ Q♥ K♠ 6⋄
UTG calls $1, MP calls $1, CO calls $1, *2 folds*, Hero checks

**Flop**: ($4.50) 7♣ Q⋄ K♣ *(4 players)*
Hero bets $4.50, *1 fold*, MP calls $4.50, CO calls $4.50

**Turn**: ($18) 3♥ *(3 players)*
Hero bets $18, *1 fold*, CO raises to $72, Hero ???

My line was to play top two fast to charge my opponents when they inevitably pursue draws on such a wet board. Faced with a large bet on the turn, how do you respond?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best case here, you are up against a broadway wrap + flush draw.  Since you didn't raise pre, CO can't put you on AA, and potting twice out of position is indicative of a lot of strength, so he is not going to be raising here as a bluff.  Best case you have to dodge half the deck, worst case you're drawing thin against a set.  **I fold.**

Answer (score 1):

You're virtually readless, aside from the very slim possibility that CO likes to slowplay his value hands. That wouldn't sway me from thinking that we are beat here, virtually all the time.

He's not folding to any action after his turn raise, and your line is as strong as it could be considering you can have any two cards due to your BB check.

I put him squarely on combinations of sets+draws, i.e. 77xx, 33xx, any mix of those with 2 clubs. It's possible that your K and Q outs to the Full House are clean but that's still only 4 outs, giving us roughly ~8% equity. Explicitly or implicitly, we can't overcome that deficit so **I fold**.

Comment: I agree that he is not folding. I think your range is too narrow though. Certainly combo draws should be included, as well as other two-pair hands (with or without a draw). 33xx should be discounted as less likely to have continued on the flop. I'd also be inclined to include A&clubs; Q&clubs; x x

Comment: @JeffreyBlake Perhaps my range is too narrow, but what info is there there to assume otherwise? In my experience widening my range assumptions in these fairly common scenarios is unsafe, as it lacks a base of understanding about the opponent. I'm cautious until I know better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are severely overplaying your hand. You are out of position against multiple opponents. You have 2 pair and no draws. You should play much this hand much more cautiously. I would definitely just check the flop.

*Pulling this out of the comments*: Basically I would try to check it down unless I hit a K or Q. If there were betting and raising along the way, I'd get out of the way. I would probably call 1 or 2 bets to see a turn and a river provided no scare cards fell. The question is: Which hand that you beat bets on flop, turn and river against this many opponents?

You talk about punishing your opponents for drawing, but you forget this is omaha. It's possible for you opponents to have draws with so many outs that you are the underdog. Against several opponents you are likely to face both flush and straight draws, not to mention hands that already have you beat. Someone could have the same 2 pair that you have but with a draw to freeroll against you. Someone could have aces along with one or both draws.

Comment: I didn't say that I wanted to punish people who were drawing - I said I wanted to charge them. I have decent equity on the flop against most drawing hands, so long as they don't already have a set or have me in the freerolling situation you describe. In my mind, that was reason enough to build the pot a bit before they give up from having missed, or I lose my equity from a draw hitting. Can you elaborate what line(s) you prefer for flop and turn, along with the reasons you feel they are better?

Comment: Basically I would try to check it down unless I hit a K or Q. If there were betting and raising along the way, I'd get out of the way. I would probably call 1 or 2 bets to see a turn and a river provided no scare cards fell. The question is: Which hand that you beat bets on flop, turn and river against this many opponents?